# C fork program behaviour explanation

Tags: c, unix, fork

I'm completly new to the C language and Unix systems. I might formulate myself badly or wrong. I have a C program where two processes increments a global variable up to 30. I am aware that order of output is random with parallel processing. **But when using the *| more* pipe, the output is always the same: Child 1-30 -> Parent 1-30. How come?**

I've been told that when using printf to print a variable, the variable content is sent to a buffer before printing to screen. And apparently you can use new line (\n) to flush the buffer right away. Is this information connected?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
int g_ant = 0; 

void writeloop(char *text) 
 {
 long i = 0;
 while (g_ant < 30) 
   {
   if (++i % 100000 == 0)
      printf("%s: %d\n", text, ++g_ant);
   }
  }

 int main(void)
  {
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) 
    {                 /* child */
    writeloop("Child");
    exit(0);
    }
  writeloop("Parent"); /* parent */
  waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your information is basically correct.

When the output goes to the terminal, the output is line buffered.  When the output goes to a pipe, the output is fully buffered, so one of the processes finishes its output first.  You could add `fflush(stdout)` after each iteration in `writeloop()`, or use `setvbuf()` to make it line buffered, or even unbuffered output.

Incidentally, note that the global variable is not shared between the child and the parent process; they each have their own copy of the variable.